# Hibernate QueryBuilder Lucene Search Spatial

Tags: hibernate, lucene, spatial, hibernate-search

Can you give me an example about usage of onCoordinates("whatIsThisString") ?
I could not find any example inculing Entity and query example together.

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(getPersistentClass()).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.spatial()
            .onCoordinates("XXX").within(100, Unit.KM).ofLatitude(latitude).andLongitude(longitude)
            .createQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

That string is the field name. In more current versions of Hibernate Search, it has been replaced with [`onField`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.7/api/org/hibernate/search/query/dsl/SpatialContext.html#onField(java.lang.String)). The documentation for versions that include this method do have examples of it's use, such as the [4.3 documentation here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#spatial-queries).